# Leer variables especificas desde un archivo Rdata

Tags: r, rstudio

Hola muy buenas a todos

Me gustaría saber si existe alguna manera de leer solo las variables que yo especifique desde un RData
que contiene un df

A modo de ejemplo, en data.table cargo así las bases y es mas rapido:

```
data.table::fread(df,select("v1,v2,...))
```

Ya que actualmente mi RData es muy pesado y solo necesito un subset de este mismo

Actualmente uso la funcion load() de R base para cargar Rdata

Encontré una libreria que se llama saves y permite cargar y guardar archivos "RDatas"

```
loads(file = NULL, variables = NULL, to.data.frame = FALSE,
  ultra.fast = FALSE)
saves(..., list = character(), file = NULL, overwrite = FALSE,
  ultra.fast = FALSE)
```

Destaco "Rdatas" porque el formato es distinto a RData, que por lo que revise es otro formato y funciona, pero aun así, sigo con la duda si se puede hacer esto del mismo archivo RData y no tener que estar guardando y leyendo los archivos con este nuevo formato.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, desde R base, que yo sepa no hay forma directa de cargar solo algunas de las columnas o variables de un `data.frame` serializado en un `RData`, lamentablemente debes cargarlo todo y eventualmente eliminar las filas que no te interesan, por ejemplo así:

```
save(mtcars, file="mtcars.Rda")

load_cols_from <- function(file, cols) {
  x <- load(file)
  get(x)[, cols]
}

mtcars2 <- load_cols_from("mtcars.Rda", c("mpg", "cyl"))
head(mtcars2)

                   mpg cyl
Mazda RX4         21.0   6
Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6
Datsun 710        22.8   4
Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6
Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8
Valiant           18.1   6
```

Alternativas:

- Leer el objeto completo y eliminar las columnas innecesarias (el ejemplo que te dí)
- Serializar los datos en un archivo CSV o similar y leer solo las columnas de interés
- Usar `sqlite` y cargar las columnas mediante un `select mpg, cyl from mtcars`
- Usar el paquete que mencionaste (`saves`) que según se lee en la documentación es mejor alternativa a todas las que hasta ahora enumeramos

Bueno, en realidad, hay también una forma un poco estrambótica pero que conceptualmente funcionaría, que es salvar las columnas en archivos separados y luego unir solo aquellas que necesitemos:

```
save_splited_df <- function(df, file) {
  
  for (c in colnames(df)) {
    file_col <- paste0(file, ".", c, ".Rds")
    saveRDS(df[,c], file_col)
  }
}

load_splited_df <- function(file, cols) {
  lista <- list()
  for (c in cols) {
    file_col <- paste0(file, ".", c, ".Rds")
    lista[[c]] <- readRDS(file_col)
  }
  do.call(cbind, lista)
}

save_splited_df(mtcars, "mtcars")
load_splited_df("mtcars", c("hp", "cyl", "mpg"))
```

Nota: pareciera que este es el concepto que usa el paquete `saves`